# Why am I getting InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private string mConfigFileName = "configData.xml";

        private void GetConfiguration() 
        {
            try
            {                
                mConfiguration = (Configuration)XmlUtility.Deserialize(mConfiguration.GetType(), mConfigFileName);                
            }
            catch 
            {
                mConfiguration = new Configuration();
            }
        }
```

I'm using a breakpoint on the line `mConfiguration = (Configuration)XmlUtility.Deserialize(mConfiguration.GetType(), mConfigFileName);` and it's going to this method:

```
public static Object Deserialize(Type type, string fileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(type);

            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(fileName);
            Object data = xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);

            xmlReader.Close();

            return data;
        }
```

Then on the line `Object data = xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);` it's jumping back to the catch of the Getconfiguration method:

```
catch 
            {
                mConfiguration = new Configuration();
            }
```

The exception:

There is an error in XML document (0, 0)

This is the xml document content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LocationX>877</LocationX>
  <LocationY>498</LocationY>
  <CloseOnMouseUp>true</CloseOnMouseUp>
  <DoubleBuffered>true</DoubleBuffered>
  <HideMouseCursor>true</HideMouseCursor>
  <RememberLastPoint>true</RememberLastPoint>
  <ReturnToOrigin>true</ReturnToOrigin>
  <ShowInTaskbar>false</ShowInTaskbar>
  <TopMostWindow>true</TopMostWindow>
  <MagnifierWidth>150</MagnifierWidth>
  <MagnifierHeight>150</MagnifierHeight>
  <ZoomFactor>3</ZoomFactor>
  <SpeedFactor>0.35</SpeedFactor>
</Configuration>
```

This is the full exception message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
       at mws.XmlUtility.Deserialize(Type type, String fileName) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\XmlUtility.cs:line 53
       at mws.MagnifierMainForm.GetConfiguration() in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\MagnifierMainForm.cs:line 110
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       HResult=-2147024894
       Message=Could not find file 'D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\bin\x86\Release\configData.xml'.
       Source=mscorlib
       FileName=D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\bin\x86\Release\configData.xml
       StackTrace:
            at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
            at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
            at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
            at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
            at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderConfiguration.Read3_Configuration()
       InnerException:
```

EDIT:

I added the xml file as file to the resources of my project.
And changed to code to:

```
private string mConfigFileName = Properties.Resources.configData;

        private void GetConfiguration() 
        {
            try
            {                
                mConfiguration = (Configuration)XmlUtility.Deserialize(mConfiguration.GetType(), mConfigFileName);                
            }
            catch 
            {
                mConfiguration = new Configuration();
            }
        }
```

Now it's jumping to the catch again with a different exception:

Illegal characters in path

```
System.ArgumentException was caught
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Illegal characters in path.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
       at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
       at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
       at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
       at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
       at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, XmlNameTable nt)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor(String url)
       at mws.XmlUtility.Deserialize(Type type, String fileName) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\XmlUtility.cs:line 52
       at mws.MagnifierMainForm.GetConfiguration() in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\MagnifierMainForm.cs:line 110
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Look at the inner exception: `InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.  It can't find `D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\bin\x86\Release\configData.xml`.

Comment: Edited my question. I can just copy the file to my current project debug or release directory but if i want to work with it on other projects or to send it to someone i will need to copy it all the time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could not find file 'D:\C-Sharp\Download
>   File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading
>   File\bin\x86\Release\configData.xml'

Check that file actually exists. If it included in solution, check that is has Content set as compile type and Copy to Output folder set to "If Newer".

Comment: PashaPash i did and i tried to add the files to my project resources. But now im getting another exception. I guess just adding the file as resource is not good. Its putting in the string in the variable mConfigFileName the content of the xml and not its file name. private string mConfigFileName = Properties.Resources.configData; on this line i see the content of the file. So how can i add the file to my project and use its name as file name not its content ?

Comment: I just now tried to set it to Compile and also to If Newer but then im getting error: Error 1 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\Resources\configData.xml 1 1 Downloading File

Comment: The error is in the xml content on the first line on the first char "<" the symbol smaller then

Comment: Now i tried to add the file the xml file as exist item to my project not as resource changed it to compile and copy if newer. But how do i use the file now in my code ?

Comment: Change type from Compile to Content. Compile is a source code. Content is just a file.